# password generator using define function

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i've been trying to create a password generator using a define function. but it's not working out.

here's the code:

```
 import random
 def pasword_gen():
     cha = ('qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm,./;[]')
     password = random.choice(cha)
     password = ''
     for c in range(10):
         password += random.choice(cha)
```

pasword_gen()

I feel like i'm missing something really obvious. but I don't know what.

Please help.

Comment: yes: you have to return `password` from the function... and assign the value to another variable.

Comment: one line: `password = "".join([random.choice('qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm,./;[]') for _ in range(10)])` no need for function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You nearly have it.

```
import random
def pasword_gen():
    cha = ('qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm,./;[]')
    password = ''
    for c in range(10):
        password += random.choice(cha)
    return password

password = pasword_gen()

print(password)
```

Notice you have to **return** the password variable

### edit

This [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm) should help clarify defining functions in python

Comment: make it `password = "".join([random.choice(cha) for _ in range(10)])` without a loop

Comment: Yes, that would definitely be an improvement. But in the interest of keeping it relative to the OP's experience I will leave it as is.

Comment: And define `cha`as `string.ascii_lowercase + ',./;[]'`.